# Setting margin-left to a certain value if less than 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, margin-left

I want to set an object's css `margin-left` property to 1000 if it's lower than 0, but it isn't working as I want.

This is the code I'm using:

```
$(".slide").each(function(a, b) {
  m=$(this).css("margin-Left");
  if (m <= "0px") {
    console.log($(this).css("margin-left"));
    $(this).css({"margin-left": width + "px"});
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that `.css('margin-left')` will return you a string.
Change your code in the following way:

```
$(".slide").each(function(a,b){
   m = parseInt($(this).css("margin-left"));
   if(m <= 0) {
      console.log($(this).css("margin-left"));
      $(this).css({"margin-left":width+"px"});
   }
});
```

Comment: Maybe use `var m = ...` to avoid creating a global variable.

Comment: @devius I believe it's only some part of his code, so I've just tweaked what I see.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setInterval()` to change the margin-left more than one time:

```
setInterval(function(){
   $(".slide").each(function(a,b){
      m = parseInt($(this).css("margin-left"));
      if(m <= 0) {
         console.log($(this).css("margin-left"));
         $(this).css({"margin-left": "1000px"});
      }
   });
}, 500);
```

Comment: Using `setInterval` is in no way related to the question.

Comment: @devius Without interval, it checked just once.

Comment: Good point, but that wasn't the problem with the original code and we don't even know if `margin-left` changes dynamically as the page is resized or new elements are added to the `.slide` class.